# How to save the encoded output in Keras

Tags: csv, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to save the encoded part just before decoder stage in autoencoder model of Keras with Tensorflow backend.

For instance;

```
encoding_dim = 210
input_img = Input(shape=(5184,))

encoded = Dense(2592, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded1 = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(encoded1)
decoded = Dense(5184, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
```

I want to save the `encoded1` as csv file after the autoencoder training. Suppose the output of `Dense` will be `(nb_samples, output_dim)`.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded1)

autoencoder.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer=my_optimizer)
autoencoder.fit(my_data, my_data, .. rest of fit params)

numpy.savetxt("encoded1.csv", encoder.predict(x), delimiter=",")
```

Moreover - I don't know what kind of data do you have but I advise you to use `linear` activation is a last layer and `mse` loss function.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore, as this will save the encoded output before fitting and training isn't it? I need to save it after autoencoder compiling and fitting.

Comment: . Actually. This would work as calling `predict` is compiling a `Keras` function. Of course model would not be fitted but I expected that you would remember about that. Moreover - you put a `sigmoid` as your activation which made me not sure about what kind of loss and optimizer you want to use. I provided a so called minimal working example with information you provided. In the future - before you unaccept the answer - please ask why something wasn't written in the answer. I would ask you for additional information and complete my answer

Comment: I thought it is working at the time, but then later on, I forgot that it is not yet fitted, as what I've asked above, without putting the autoencoder code. Thanks for the explanation. Somehow, the code that you have edited does not take into account the 2 other layers of decoded part.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko How do I load back the data? I tried "np.genfromtxt('encoded1.csv', delimiter=',')" but I get an error : "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" when using the data